# Accessing the contents in a vector of lists

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I have a vector of lists and I am trying to access the contents of the list at an index in the array and then return a pointer to the index of the list.

The if statement is the problem, but I have tried different solutions and nothing seems to be working.

```
VALTYPE *find(KEYTYPE key) {
int temp = hash_function(key);
VALTYPE *p = nullptr;
if (hashT[temp].begin() == key)
{
    p = hashT[temp];
}
return p;
}

C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Word>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'std::list<VALTYPE,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'Word *'
```

Comment: [mcve] please, need to see the actual types of everything and the actual error message.

Comment: I added the error messages @Mat

Comment: @DreamsOfElectricSheep In the debugger I can see the contents of my vector of lists, but I do not know how to access the contents in the list

Comment: Errors are pretty clear, `KEYTYPE` is not an iterator and a pointer is not a list. You might want to re read over the `std::list` bit of your material.

Comment: When I wrote that comment id only read the text, not code so it wasn't clear, sorry :)

Comment: @DreamsOfElectricSheep all good :)

Comment: @DreamsOfElectricSheep Is it possible to dereference an iterator? I realize now my code won't work because .begin() returns an iterator, but I am still not sure how get the contents.

Comment: Yes, do your lists only contain keys? o.O Also where are valtypes supposed to be retrieved from? Oh, and dereferencing works the same way as it does for pointers.

Comment: The lists contains strings, valtype is just the template so that the vector of lists can theoretically store anything. Its a vector of lists, and the lists actually store the words while the key (is a hash) that gives an index to where the words are. @DreamsOfElectricSheep